# python 3.5.2 UdpServer sendto() error: module 'socket' has no attribute 'sendto'

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, networking, attributes

I've problem with python socket  at `s.sendto(data,addr)`
and my code like this

```
import socket

    def Main():
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        port = 5000
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.bind((host, port))
        print("server started")
        while True:
            data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)

            print ("message from : "+ str(addr))
            print ("from connected user : "+ str(data))
            data = str(data.upper())
            print ("sending : "+ str(data))
            socket.sendto(data, addr)
```

and result

```
    socket.sendto(data, addr)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'sendto'
        s.close()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Main()
```

and at UdpClient `s.sendto` is working

Comment: hi! stupid question without testing it... wouldn't it be `s.sendto()` instead of `socket.sendto()`?

Comment: think you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you mistyped the `socket.sendto(...` statement: The AttributeError is raised since the method sendto() is to be called from instances of the class `socket.socket` (as you have in `s`), and not from the `socket`module itself. See [here](http://reeborg.ca/docs/oop_py_en/oop.html) for more details about the meaning of that statement.

So you basically need to change `socket.sendto(...` to `s.sendto(...`

also, if you want to check the attributes of any `x` object,(apart from reading the docs) you can simply check its `x.__dict__` field, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/python-explain-dict-attribute)

cheers