# Setting default/empty attributes for user classes in __init__

Tags: python, class, instance, instance-variables, python-attrs

When I am creating a new class, should I set all instance attributes in `__init__`, even if they are `None` and in fact later assigned values in class methods?

See example below for the attribute `results` of `MyClass`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,df):
          self.df = df
          self.results = None

    def results(df_results):
         #Imagine some calculations here or something
         self.results = df_results
```

I have found in other projects, class attributes can get buried when they only appear in class methods and there is a lot going.

So to an experienced professional programmer what is standard practice for this? Would you define all instance attributes in `__init__` for readability?

Comment: I would initialise everything in `__init__`, even if `None` initially.  It makes it clear what the instance data attributes are, and prevents `AttributeErrors` on `self` when using the instance (though of course other exceptions are still possible).

Comment: Building on first comment: if you _don't_ do this, you may later be wondering, _has this been initialized?_ when looking at one of your attributes and wondering if you can read from it without presence checking in some method. If everything's in `__init__`, you know (a.) it's all there and (b.) it's been initialized in the most sensible place, where you'd look first.

Comment: As an alternate perspective: it sounds like you're defining a class of objects where some attributes are not valid on some objects in that class. That's problematic from a OO perspective. If you have a method that calculates results, perhaps it should *return* an object representing the results rather than *mutating* the current object? If you avoid the need for attributes defined outside of `__init__` then this problem disappears.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daniel but I'm not doing that. All attributes will be valid on all instances, is just that some are assigned values later on through methods rather than on __init__

Comment: @Andy: That's what I meant by "valid". If an attribute doesn't have a value assigned yet, then it's not "valid" in the sense that it can't be used. Yes, you can use a "placeholder" value, and `None` is the normal choice for such a placeholder, but a better design would be to avoid the placeholder if possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Following considerable research and discussions with experienced programmers please see below what I believe is the most Pythonic solution to this question. I have included the updated code first and then a narrative:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,df):
          self.df = df
          self._results = None

    @property
    def results(self):
        if self._results is None:
            raise Exception('df_client is None')
        return self._results

    def generate_results(self, df_results):
         #Imagine some calculations here or something
         self._results = df_results
```

Description of what I learnt, changed and why:

1. All class attributes should be included in the `__init__` (initialiser) method. This is to ensure readability and aid debugging.
2. The first issue is that you cannot create private attributes in Python. Everything is public, so any partially initialised attributes (such as results being set to None) can be accessed. Convention to indicate a private attribute is to place a lead underscore at the front, so in this case I changed it to `self.results` to `self._results`.

   Keep in mind this is only convention, and `self._results` can still be directly accessed. However, this is the Pythonic way to handle what are pseudo-private attributes.
3. The second issue is having a partly initialised attribute which is set to None. As this is set to `None`, as @jferard below explains, we now have lost a fail-fast hint and have added a layer of obfuscation for debugging the code.

   To resolve this we add a getter method. This can be seen above as the function `results()` which has the `@property` decorator above.

   This is a function that when invoked checks if `self._results` is `None`. If so it will raise an exception (fail-safe hint), otherwise it will return the object. The `@property` decorator changes the invocation style from a function to an attribute, so all the user has to use on an instance of MyClass is `.results` just like any other attribute.

   (I changed the name of the method that sets the results to `generate_results()` to avoid confusion and free up `.results` for the getter method)
4. If you then have other methods within the class that need to use `self._results`, but only when properly assigned, you can use `self.results`, and that way the fail-safe hint is baked in as above.

I recommend also reading @jferard's answer to this question. He goes into depth about the problems and some of the solutions. The reason I added my answer is that I think for a lot of cases the above is all you need (and the Pythonic way of doing it).

Comment: This is a nice solution to the problem (and very helpful for a problem I'm currently struggling with, so thank you for posting it). One suggestion for improving the solution: raise a more specific exception than just `Exception`. If you raise a generic `Exception`, then you have to catch **all** kinds of errors in a `try/except` block when you're retrieving the attribute somewhere else. If you raise a more specific exception such as `AttributeError`, it will be much easier to work with.

Comment: I'm afraid your very first point is wrong. First, a pythonic way is to write documentation on methods/attributes. Then you don't make readers read your *init* code. Second, you can test whether the attribute was set by try/except block (a pythonic way). If you get an *AttributeError*, then your field was not set. Also, for me *None* is a magic constant. You have to read another method to understand that that is an unacceptable value.

Answer (score 32):

I think you should avoid both solutions. Simply because you should avoid to create uninitialized or partially initialized objects, except in one case I will outline later.

Look at two slightly modified version of your class, with a setter and a getter:

```
class MyClass1:
    def __init__(self, df):
          self.df = df
          self.results = None

    def set_results(self, df_results):
         self.results = df_results

    def get_results(self):
         return self.results
```

And

```
class MyClass2:
    def __init__(self, df):
          self.df = df

    def set_results(self, df_results):
         self.results = df_results

    def get_results(self):
         return self.results
```

The only difference between `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` is that the first one initializes `results` in the constructor while the second does it in `set_results`. Here comes the user of your class (usually you, but not always). Everyone knows you can't trust the user (even if it's you):

```
MyClass1("df").get_results()
# returns None
```

Or

```
MyClass2("df").get_results()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# ...
# AttributeError: 'MyClass2' object has no attribute 'results'
```

You might think that the first case is better because it does not fail, but I do not agree. I would like the program to fail fast in this case, rather than do a long debugging session to find what happened. Hence, **the first part of  first answer is: *do not set the uninitialized fields to `None`, because you loose a fail-fast hint*.**

But that's not the whole answer. Whichever version you choose, you have an issue: the object was not used and it shouldn't have been, because it was not fully initialized. You can add a docstring to `get_results`: `"""Always use` set_results `**BEFORE** this method"""`. Unfortunately the user doesn't read docstrings either.

You have two main reasons for uninitialized fields in your object: 1. you don't know (for now) the value of the field; 2. you want to avoid an expansive operation (computation, file access, network, ...), aka "lazy initialization". Both situations are met in real world, and collide the need of using only fully initialized objects.

Happily, there is a well documented solution to this problem: Design Patterns, and more precisely [Creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). In your case, the Factory pattern or the Builder pattern might be the answer. E.g.:

```
class MyClassBuilder:
    def __init__(self, df):
          self._df = df # df is known immediately
          # GIVE A DEFAULT VALUE TO OTHER FIELDS to avoid the possibility of a partially uninitialized object.
          # The default value should be either:
          # * a value passed as a parameter of the constructor ;
          # * a sensible value (eg. an empty list, 0, etc.)

    def results(self, df_results):
         self._results = df_results
         return self # for fluent style
         
    ... other field initializers

    def build(self):
        return MyClass(self._df, self._results, ...)

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, df, results, ...):
          self.df = df
          self.results = results
          ...
          
    def get_results(self):
         return self.results
    
    ... other getters
```

(You can use a Factory too, but I find the Builder more flexible). Let's give a second chance to the user:

```
>>> b = MyClassBuilder("df").build()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: 'MyClassBuilder' object has no attribute '_results'
>>> b = MyClassBuilder("df")
>>> b.results("r")
... other fields iniialization
>>> x = b.build()
>>> x
<__main__.MyClass object at ...>
>>> x.get_results()
'r'
```

The advantages are clear:

1. It's easier to detect and fix a creation failure than a late use failure;
2. You do not release in the wild a uninitialized (and thus potentially damaging) version of your object.

The presence of uninitialized fields in the Builder is not a contradiction: those fields are uninitialized by design, because the Builder's role is to initialize them. (Actually, those fields are some kind of forein fields to the Builder.) This is the case I was talking about in my introduction. They should, in my mind, be set to a default value (if it exists) or left uninitialized to raise an exception if you try to create an uncomplete object.

**Second part of my answer: *use a Creational pattern to ensure the object is correctly initialized*.**

Side note: I'm very suspicious when I see a class with getters **and** setters. My rule of thumb is: always try to separate them because when they meet, objects become unstable.

Comment: Thanks @jferard, a realy helpful run through. On your final side note, why don't you like a class with both getters and setters? I thought that was how most people applied them. How do you seperate them?

Comment: @Andy I guess that's because of this remark that this answer was downvoted, hence I will try to make it clear. The idea is that it is easier to understand (and test) a program when most of the objects are immmutable. If you have getters and setters, objects are basically mutable, and their current state is often uncertain (it is worse if your program is concurrent).

Comment: Sometimes, you really need mutable objects, but most of the time, you need the setters to initialize the object *and then* the getters to use the object. In this case, a creational pattern will isolate the setters (in a builder for instance) from the getters and the created object will be immutable, as in the given example. This removes the risk of late initalization or unwanted mutation of the object and makes the tests easy.

Comment: Thanks @jferard for the follow up. I need to reflect on this a bit longer. I thought one of the core powers of OOP is modifying the attributes of instantiated objects to achieve the objective of the program i.e. that they are mutable. I understand that debugging is easier if your objects are immutable, but then surely your coding style is becoming more similar to a functional language? Please excuse my ignorance if my comment here is very far off the mark!

Comment: @Andy Of course, mutable objects are very useful. If you have a `BankAccount` instance, you want the `deposit/withdrawal` methods to change the balance. In this case, you will have a getter, but no setter, for `balance`. When you have getters **and** setters, it's very often because you are dealing with a simple data structure dressed up like a class. I really prefer to handle immutable data structures, that's why I'm cautious with classes that have getters and setters.

Comment: @jferard PyCharm gives the following warning for `MyClassBuilder`: `Instance attribute _results defined outside __init__ `. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @BubbleMaster PyCharm is right. Note that I wrote as a comment `# give a default value to other fields if possible`. I should have used a stronger wording. If you do not give a default value to all the fields, you get this warning because the object may be unitialized. `MyClassBuyilder().build()` should return a valid object (as a default constructor would do). See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the importance(or not) of initializing attributes in `__init__`, let's take a modified version of your class `MyClass` as an example. The purpose of the class is to compute the grade for a subject, given the student name and score. You may follow along in a Python interpreter.

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self,name,score):
...         self.name = name
...         self.score = score
...         self.grade = None
...
...     def results(self, subject=None):
...         if self.score >= 70:
...             self.grade = 'A'
...         elif 50 <= self.score < 70:
...             self.grade = 'B'
...         else:
...             self.grade = 'C'
...         return self.grade
```

This class requires two positional arguments `name` and `score`. These arguments *must* be provided to initialize a class instance. Without these, the class object `x` cannot be instantiated and a `TypeError` will be raised:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'name' and 'score'
```

At this point, we understand that we must provide the `name` of the student and a `score` for a subject as a minimum, but the `grade` is not important right now because that will be computed later on, in the `results` method. So, we just use `self.grade = None` and don't define it as a positional arg. Let's initialize a class instance(object):

```
>>> x = MyClass(name='John', score=70)
>>> x
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000002491F0AE898>
```

The `<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000002491F0AE898>` confirms that the class object `x` was successfully created at the given memory location. Now, Python provides some useful built-in methods to view the attributes of the created class object. One of the methods is `__dict__`. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/python-explain-dict-attribute):

```
>>> x.__dict__
{'name': 'John', 'score': 70, 'grade': None}
```

This clearly gives a `dict` view of all the initial attributes and their values. Notice, that `grade` has a `None` value as assigned in `__init__`.

Let's take a moment to understand what `__init__` does. There are many [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625083/python-init-and-self-what-do-they-do) and online resources available to explain what this method does but I'll summarize:

Like `__init__`, Python has another built-in method called `__new__()`. When you create a class object like this `x = MyClass(name='John', score=70)`, Python internally calls `__new__()` first to create a new instance of the class `MyClass` and then calls `__init__` to initialize the attributes `name` and `score`. Of course, in these internal calls when Python does not find the values for the required positional args, it raises an error as we've seen above. In other words, `__init__` initializes the attributes. You can assign new initial values for `name` and `score` like this:

```
>>> x.__init__(name='Tim', score=50)
>>> x.__dict__
{'name': 'Tim', 'score': 50, 'grade': None}
```

It is also possible to access individual attributes like below. `grade` does not give anything because it is `None`.

```
>>> x.name
'Tim'
>>> x.score
50
>>> x.grade
>>>
```

In the `results` method, you will notice that the `subject` "variable" is defined as `None`, a positional arg. The scope of this variable is inside this method only. For the purposes of demonstration, I explicitly define `subject` inside this method but this could have been initialized in `__init__` too. But what if I try to access it with my object:

```
>>> x.subject
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'subject'
```

Python raises an `AttributeError` when it cannot locate an attribute within the class's namespace. If you do not initialize attributes in `__init__`, there is a possibility to encounter this error when you access an undefined attribute that could be local to the method of a class only. In this example, defining `subject` inside `__init__` would have avoided the confusion and would've been perfectly normal to do so as it is not required for any computation either.

Now, lets call `results` and see what we get:

```
>>> x.results()
'B'
>>> x.__dict__
{'name': 'Tim', 'score': 50, 'grade': 'B'}
```

This prints the grade for the score and notice when we view the attributes, the `grade` has also been updated. Right from the start, we had a clear view of the initial attributes and how their values have changed.

But what about `subject`? If I want to know how much Tim scored in Math and what was the grade, I can easily access the `score` and the `grade` as we've seen before but how do I know the subject? Since, the `subject` variable is local to the scope of the `results` method we could just `return` the value of `subject`. Change the `return` statement in the `results` method:

```
def results(self, subject=None):
    #<---code--->
    return self.grade, subject
```

Let's call `results()` again. We get a tuple with the grade and subject as expected.

```
>>> x.results(subject='Math')
('B', 'Math')
```

To access the values in the tuple, let's assign them to variables. In Python, it is possible to assign values from a collection to multiple variables in the same expression, provided that the number of variables is equal to the length of the collection. Here, the length is just two, so we can have two variables to the left of the expression:

```
>>> grade, subject = x.results(subject='Math')
>>> subject
'Math'
```

So, there we have it, though it needed a few extra lines of code to get the `subject`. It would be more intuitive to access all of them at once using just the dot operator to access the attributes with `x.<attribute>`, but this is just an example and you could try it with `subject` initialized in `__init__`.

Next, consider there are many students(say 3) and we want the names, scores, grades for Math. Except the subject, all others must be some sort of a collection data type like a `list` that can store all the names, scores and grades. We could just initialize like this:

```
>>> x = MyClass(name=['John', 'Tom', 'Sean'], score=[70, 55, 40])
>>> x.name
['John', 'Tom', 'Sean']
>>> x.score
[70, 55, 40]
```

This seems fine at first sight, but when you take a another look(or some other programmer) at the initialization of `name`, `score` and `grade` in `__init__`, there is no way to tell that they need a collection data type. The variables are also named singular making it more obvious that they could be just some random variables that may need just one value. The purpose of programmers should be to make the intent as clear as as possible, by way of descriptive variable naming, type declarations, code comments and so on. With this in mind, let's change the attribute declarations in `__init__`. Before we settle for a *well-behaved*, *well-defined* declaration, we must take care of how we declare default arguments.

---

**Edit**: Problems with mutable default arguments:

Now, there are some 'gotchas' that we must be aware of while declaring default args. Consider the following declaration that initializes `names` and appends a random name on object creation. Recall that lists are mutable objects in Python.

```
#Not recommended
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,names=[]):
        self.names = names
        self.names.append('Random_name')
```

Let's see what happens when we create objects from this class:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x.names
['Random_name']
>>> y = MyClass()
>>> y.names
['Random_name', 'Random_name']
```

The list continues to grow with every new object creation. The reason behind this is that the default values are *always* evaluated whenever `__init__` is called. Calling `__init__` multiple times, keeps using the same function object thus appending to the previous set of default values. You can verify this yourself as the `id` remains the same for every object creation.

```
>>> id(x.names)
2513077313800
>>> id(y.names)
2513077313800
```

So, what is the correct way of defining default args while also being explicit about the data type the attribute supports? The safest option is to set default args to `None` and initialize to an empty list when the arg values are `None`. The following is a recommended way to declare default args:

```
#Recommended
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self,names=None):
...         self.names = names if names else []
...         self.names.append('Random_name')
```

Let's examine the behavior:

```
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x.names
['Random_name']
>>> y = MyClass()
>>> y.names
['Random_name']
```

Now, this behavior is what we are looking for. The object does not "carry over" old baggage and re-initializes to an empty list whenever no values are passed to `names`. If we pass some valid names (as a list of course) to the `names` arg for the `y` object, `Random_name` will simply be appended to this list. And again, the `x` object values will not be affected:

```
>>> y = MyClass(names=['Viky','Sam'])
>>> y.names
['Viky', 'Sam', 'Random_name']
>>> x.names
['Random_name']
```

Perhaps, the most simplest explanation on this concept can also be found on the [Effbot website](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm). If you'd like to read some excellent answers: [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

---

Based on the brief discussion on default args, our class declarations will be modified to:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,names=None, scores=None):
        self.names = names if names else []
        self.scores = scores if scores else []
        self.grades = []
#<---code------>
```

This makes more sense, all variables have plural names and initialized to empty lists on object creation. We get similar results as before:

```
>>> x.names
['John', 'Tom', 'Sean']
>>> x.grades
[]
```

`grades` is an empty list making it clear that the grades will be computed for multiple students when `results()` is called. Therefore, our `results` method should also be modified. The comparisons that we make should now be between the score numbers(70, 50 etc.) and items in the `self.scores` list and while it does that the `self.grades` list should also be updated with the individual grades. Change the `results` method to:

```
def results(self, subject=None):
    #Grade calculator 
    for i in self.scores:
        if i >= 70:
            self.grades.append('A')
        elif 50 <= i < 70:
            self.grades.append('B')
        else:
            self.grades.append('C')
    return self.grades, subject
```

We should now get the grades as a list when we call `results()`:

```
>>> x.results(subject='Math')
>>> x.grades
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> x.names
['John', 'Tom', 'Sean']
>>> x.scores
[70, 55, 40]
```

This looks good but imagine if the lists were large and to figure out who's score/grade belongs to whom would be an absolute nightmare. This is where it is important to initialize the attributes with the correct data type that can store all of these items in a way that they are easily accessible as well as clearly show their relationships. The best choice here is a dictionary.

We can have a dictionary with names and scores defined initially and the `results` function should put together everything into a new dictionary that has all the scores, grades etc. We should also comment the code properly and explicitly define args in the method wherever possible. Lastly, we may not require `self.grades` anymore in `__init__` because as you will see the grades are not being appended to a list but explicitly assigned. This is totally dependent upon the requirements of the problem.

**The final code**:

```
class MyClass:
"""A class that computes the final results for students"""

    def __init__(self,names_scores=None):

        """initialize student names and scores
        :param names_scores: accepts key/value pairs of names/scores
                         E.g.: {'John': 70}"""

        self.names_scores = names_scores if names_scores else {}     

    def results(self, _final_results={}, subject=None):
        """Assign grades and collect final results into a dictionary.

       :param _final_results: an internal arg that will store the final results as dict. 
                              This is just to give a meaningful variable name for the final results."""

        self._final_results = _final_results
        for key,value in self.names_scores.items():
            if value >= 70:
                self.names_scores[key] = [value,subject,'A']
            elif 50 <= value < 70:
                self.names_scores[key] = [value,subject,'B']
            else:
                self.names_scores[key] = [value,subject,'C']
        self._final_results = self.names_scores #assign the values from the updated names_scores dict to _final_results
        return self._final_results
```

Please note `_final_results` is just an internal arg that stores the updated dict `self.names_scores`. The purpose is to return a more meaningful variable from the function that clearly informs the **intent**. The `_` in the beginning of this variable indicates that it is an internal variable, as per convention.

Lets give this a final run:

```
>>> x = MyClass(names_scores={'John':70, 'Tom':50, 'Sean':40})
>>> x.results(subject='Math')  

  {'John': [70, 'Math', 'A'],
 'Tom': [50, 'Math', 'B'],
 'Sean': [40, 'Math', 'C']}
```

This gives a much clearer view of the results for each student. It is now easy to access the grades/scores for any student:

```
>>> y = x.results(subject='Math')
>>> y['John']
[70, 'Math', 'A']
```

**Conclusion**:

While the final code needed some extra hard work but it was worth it. The output is more precise and gives clear information about each students' results. The code is more readable and clearly informs the reader about the intent of creating the class, methods, & variables. The following are the key takeaways from this discussion:

- The variables(attributes) that are expected to be shared amongst class methods, should be defined in `__init__`. In our example, `names`, `scores` and possibly `subject` were required by `results()`. These attributes could be shared by another method like say `average` that computes the average of the scores.
- The attributes should be initialized with the appropriate *data type*. This should be decided before-hand before venturing into a class-based design for a problem.
- Care must be taken while declaring attributes with default args. Mutable default args can mutate the values of the attribute if the enclosing `__init__` is causing mutation of the attribute on every call. It is safest to declare default args as `None` and re-initialize to an empty mutable collection later whenever the default value is `None`.
- The attribute names should be unambiguous, follow PEP8 guidelines.
- Some variables should be initialized within the scope of the class method only. These could be, for example, internal variables that are required for computations or variables that don't need to be shared with other methods.
- Another compelling reason to define variables in `__init__` is to avoid possible `AttributeError`s that may occur due to accessing unnamed/out-of-scope attributes. The `__dict__` built-in method provides a view of the attributes initialized here.
- While assigning values to attributes(positional args) on class instantiation, the attribute names should be explicitly defined. For instance:

  ```
  x = MyClass('John', 70)  #not explicit
  x = MyClass(name='John', score=70) #explicit
  ```
- Finally, the aim should be to **communicate the intent** as clearly as possible with comments. The class, its methods and attributes should be well commented. For all attributes, a short description alongwith an example, is quite useful for a new programmer who encounters your class and its attributes for the first time.

Comment: This is a thorough write-up, but I can't upvote it because you're encouraging the use of mutable default arguments without explaining how problematic they are.

Comment: Daniel could you elaborate a little on what you mean by 'encouraging the use of mutable default arguments'?

Comment: @DanielPryden, thanks for pointing this out. I'll update the answer soon. This is one of the 'gotchas' in Python that I've begun to understand now.

Comment: @DanielPryden, I've just updated the answer with some useful information on the problems with mutable default arguments and also edited the code accordingly. Please do let me know, if the answer can be improved in any away.

Comment: If you use `from pystrict import strict \n @strict \n class Firebird: ...`, then it will be a runtime error to create attrs outside of init.

Comment: "This class requires two positional arguments name and score." - is it really needed information here? Why don't you remove those several paragraphs. It would definitely shorten the answer (and probably in other places too).

Answer (score 1):

It's good practice to set sane default values in most applications (this solves errors with possible missing values) - so you only have to worry about data validation.

In python `3.7+` you can use [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) to set default values. Python creates default [special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-special-method) under the hood so the class is easy to read.

It's also good practice to write & comment your code so it can be easily followed by others.

In an app which reads user config from `yaml` I used a [variation of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56883874/555451) to solve possible missing configuration values:

```
class Settings():

   def __init__(self):
      """ read values from the 'Default' dataclass &
          subsequently overwrite with values from YAML.
      """
      # set default values
      self.set_defaults()

      # overwrite defaults with values from yaml
      config = self.get_config()

      # read a dict into class attributes
      for key, value in config.items():
         setattr(self, key, value)


   def set_defaults(self):
      """ sets default application values from dataclass
      """
      for name, field in   self.Default.__dataclass_fields__.items():
         setattr(self, name, field.default)


    # subclass with default values
    # dataclasses require python 3.7
    @dataclass
    class Default:
       """ Stores default values for the app.
           Called by main class: 'Settings'
       """
       cache_dir: bool = False
       cleanup: bool = True
       .....


    def get_config(self):
       """ read config file """
       ...
```

In the final code I also made the main class a `singleton` as only one copy of the object needs to exist to store configuration settings. Credit [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64545504/555451) for inspiration.

Comment: As I understand from your link, the purpose of *dataclass* is to create an *init* function for your object. In your variant, you already have an *init* method, so probably you don't need a separate dataclass here.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko - In `__init__()` I set default values from the dataclass & then override them with the users settings - https://github.com/itoffshore/distrobuilder-menu/blob/main/src/distrobuilder_menu/config/user.py - to ensure the app has no missing values set. It seems to work quite well (no bugs)