# How to correctly type an asyncio class instance variables

Tags: python, python-asyncio, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Consider the following example class containing attributes that require running a coroutine for initialization:

```py
class Example:
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self._connection: Optional[Connection] = None

  async def connect() -> None:
    self._connection = await connect_somewhere(...)

  async def send(data: bytes) -> None:
    self._connection.send(data)
```

If I run mypy (perhaps with strict-optional enabled) on this example, it will complain that `_connection` can be None in `send` method and the code is not type-safe. I can't initialize the `_connection` variable in `__init__`, as it needs to be run asynchronously in a coroutine. It's probably a bad idea to declare the variable outside `__init__` too. Is there any way to solve this? Or do you recommend another (OOP) design that would solve the issue?

Currently, I either ignore the mypy complaints, prepend `assert self._connection` before each usage or append `# type: ignore` after the usage.

Comment: Not a dupe, but related to this question, which you may find helpful & informative: [Setting default/empty attributes for user classes in `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800218/setting-default-empty-attributes-for-user-classes-in-init)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally not good design to have classes in an unusable state unless some method is called on them. An alternative is [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and an alternative constructor:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

# not strictly needed – one can also use just 'Example'
# if inheritance is not needed
T = TypeVar('T')

class Example:
    # class always receives a fully functioning connection
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection) -> None:
        self._connection = connection

    # class can construct itself asynchronously without a connection
    @classmethod
    async def connect(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls(await connect_somewhere(...))

    async def send(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        self._connection.send(data)
```

This frees `__init__` from relying on some other initialiser to be called later on; as a bonus, it is possible to provide a different connection, e.g. for testing.

The alternative constructor, here `connect`, still allows to create the object in a self-contained way (without the callee knowing how to connect) but with full `async` support.

```py
async def example():
    # create instance asynchronously
    sender = await Example.connect()
    await sender.send(b"Hello ")
    await sender.send(b"World!")
```

---

To get the full life-cycle of opening *and closing*, supporting `async with` is the most straightforward approach. This can be supported in a similar way to the alternative constructor – by providing an alternative construct *as a context manager*:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type, AsyncIterable
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

T = TypeVar('T')

class Example:
    def __init__(self, connection: Connection) -> None:
        self._connection = connection

    @asynccontextmanager
    @classmethod
    async def scope(cls: Type[T]) -> AsyncIterable[T]:
        connection = await connect_somewhere(...)  # use `async with` if possible! 
        try:
            yield cls(connection)
        finally:
            connection.close()

    async def send(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        self._connection.send(data)
```

Alternative `connect` constructor omitted for brevity. For Python 3.6, `asynccontextmanager` can be fetched from [the `asyncstdlib`](https://asyncstdlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (Disclaimer: I maintain this library).

There is a general caveat: closing does leave objects in an unusable – thus inconsistent – state practically by definition. Python's type system has no way to separate "open `Connection`" from "closed `Connection`", and especially not to detect that `.close` or the end of a context transitions from one to the other.

By using `async with` one partially side-steps this issue, since context managers are generally understood not to be useable after their block by convention.

```py
async def example():
    async with Example.scope() as sender:
        await sender.send(b"Hello ")
        await sender.send(b"World!")
```

Comment: This x100. It's hard to type correctly *because* it's an unwise thing to do to initialise an object outside of an `__init__` method. The typing issues are symptomatic of broader design issues.

Comment: This solution looks reasonable, I will try it in practice. I see two downsides though: what if you want to close the connection gracefully? Then you get to similar state as when the `_connection` is None before calling `connect`. Also the dependency injection brings a bit of extra boilerplate code to a lot of classes.

Comment: @Lefty Not to argue, but to shed some background from experience on this: As for the second part, you will have boilerplate either way – either to inject the connection or to work around the fact that there might not be a connection. The advantage of this approach (IMO) is that you can pull all that boilerplate into the class, and indeed a few methods; an optional attribute or worse an inconsistent state bleeds out every code interacting with the class.

Comment: @Lefty As for the first – if you need a well-defined open-close cycle, *do use ``async with``* (I might actually add that to the answer). This is admittedly very tricky to do in the ``async`` case because you cannot fully rely on ``__del__`` if someone messes up *and* the entire context manager protocol practically forces you to have an inconsistent state after the context. There really isn't much *practical* one can do other than pretending the object ceases to exist after closing; one can add automatic errors but that's it.

Comment: I agree this is probably the best we can get from Python, thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

> It's probably a bad idea to declare the variable outside `__init__` too

This is close. You have to annotate it outside of `__init__`.

```
class Example:
    _connection: Connection

    async def connect(self) -> None:
        self._connection = await connect_somewhere(…)
```