# How to determine an object's value in Python

Tags: python, object, expression

From the Documentation

> Every object has an identity, a type and a value.

- `type(obj)` returns the type of the object
- `id(obj)` returns the id of the object

is there something that returns its value? What does the value of an object such as a user defined object represent?

Comment: `obj` itself is a value

Comment: `obj` is the value of the object you are talking about.

Comment: ok so when I say something such as print(obj) how is obj evaluated?

Comment: @ColinHicks it calls `str(obj)` if __str__() is defined or   `repr(obj)`  you can redefined that also with `__repr__` .

Comment: @ColinHicks You don't print an object, what you print is some text that represents some information about the object.

Comment: `obj` itself will return the value.

Comment: It represents whatever the class was designed to represent

Comment: Everything in python is an object, and objects represent values in the same way that numerals represent numbers. It isn't really possible to "return" an object's value: all you can ever really do is display the value in the form of a *string-representation*.

Comment: @ColinHicks the value of the object is not the object itself but rather what is contained in the object. The information stored inside the object

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for that comment, it's the first time that the idea of "object value" started make sense to me.

Comment: @ekhumoro That's deep. Indeed, i think that in general it is always a matter of representing a newly defined concept in previously understood terms. If we understand 'strings' (or more fundamentally, bit arrays), then we can use them to represent new notions (like numbers), and later represent new concepts using numbers.

Answer (score 2):

to really see your object values/attributes you should use the [magic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/python-explain-dict-attribute) `__dict__`.

Here is a simple example:

```
class My:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.pow2_x = x ** 2

a = My(10)
# print is not helpful as you can see 
print(a) 
# output: <__main__.My object at 0x7fa5c842db00>

print(a.__dict__.values())
# output: dict_values([10, 100])
```

or you can use:

```
print(a.__dict__.items())
# output: dict_items([('x', 10), ('pow2_x', 100)])
```

Answer (score 0):

For every Python class, there are special functions executed for different cases. `__str__` of a class returns the value that will be used when called as `print(obj)` or `str(obj)`.

Example:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5

    def __str__(self):
        return "A: {0}".format(self.a)

obj = A()

print(obj)
# Will print "A: 5"
```

Comment: an object may not have `__dict__`  implemented, then what?

Comment: wouldn't ```__dict__``` be inherited from object for all new-style classes?

Comment: also did you mean print(obj)? I tried the code snippet above and it didn't work

Comment: @AswinMurugesh It is wrong to say that `__str__` returns a *value*. What it actually does is return a *string-representation* of the object. Also, [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#object.__dict__) has nothing whatsoever to do with [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Comment: @ekhumoro when I try to include any`__dict__`   attribute in a class seems thing to break. From what I’ve read, doing so is actually shadows an instances dictionary such that `trying obj.__dict__[‘attr’]` returned an error when it would otherwise return obj.attr. Is this correct? If so does that mean` __dict__ `should not be overridden as a class attribute?

Comment: @ColinHicks Yes. There is rarely any need to override `__dict__`, and it really has nothing to do with `dict`. I think they may have thinking of the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function, and the related [`__dir__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__dir__) method.

Comment: @ColinHicks PS: the [vars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function is more closely related to `__dict__`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that not all objects have a `__dict__` attribute, and moreover, sometimes calling `dict(a)` where the object `a` can actually be interpreted as a dictionary will result in a sensible conversion of `a` to a native python dictionary.  For example, with numpy arrays:

```py
In [41]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [42]: dict(a)
Out[42]: {1: 2, 3: 4}
```

But `a` does not have an attribute `1` whose value is `2`.  Instead, you can use `hasattr` and `getattr` to dynamically check for an object's attributes:

```py
In [43]: hasattr(a, '__dict__')
Out[43]: False

In [44]: hasattr(a, 'sum')
Out[44]: True

In [45]: getattr(a, 'sum')
Out[45]: <function ndarray.sum>
```

So, `a` does not have `__dict__` as an attribute, but it does have `sum` as an attribute, and `a.sum` is `getattr(a, 'sum')`.

If you want to see all the attributes that `a` has, you can use `dir`:

```py
In [47]: dir(a)[:5]
Out[47]: ['T', '__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__array__']
```

(I only showed the first 5 attributes since numpy arrays have lots.)