# Replace class instance with function inside the class (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to replace the class instance "model" with a new instance. **This should happen in a reset function inside the class.** I could easily do `model = Model(number = 2)` outside of the class, but that is not what I need.

The number thing is just an easy example for you. My actual task is totally different. **In summary I need to create a new instance with the same name, because I need a new run of the __init__. And this has to happen inside the reset function**. I hope you understand what I mean. My `reset` function does not work unfortunately:

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def reset(self):
        self = Model(number = 2)

model = Model(number = 1)
print(model.number) #it is 1

model.reset()
print(model.number) #it is 1 aswell, should be 2 :(
```

Comment: You cannot change the identity of an object, if that is what you are asking. You can *mutate* your object to have *the same relevant values*, in this case, reset would simply do `self.number=2`. But why isn't `mode = Model(2)` what you need, precisely?

Comment: You just ended up assigning newly created instance to a local variable `self`. You cannot replace object with another object in-place. You `reset` should really just set the instance to its desired / initial state by setting its attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reassign self iside of your class, but you can do something like that:

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def reset(self):
        self.__dict__ = Model(number = 2).__dict__

model = Model(number = 1)
print(model.number) #it is 1

model.reset()
print(model.number) #it is 2 :)
```

Read more about **dict** attribute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/explain-dict-attribute)

Comment: What about calling the `__init__` method instead?

Comment: This is not creating a new instance though, which might be important.

Comment: Why do this? Why not just `self.number = 2`. Note, this breaks shared-key namespace dicts...

Answer (score 1):

What about this here? Is it allowed to run the **init** manual in the `reset` function?

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def reset(self):
        self.__init__(2)

model = Model(number = 1)
print(model.number) #it is 1

model.reset()
print(model.number) #it is 2 now
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace the class instance "model" with a new instance.

All you have to do is to rebind the name `model`.

Use

```
model = Model(number=2)
```

or

```
model = Model(model.number + 1)
```

If you want to increment `number` automatically on instantiation, you could use something like this:

```
class Model:
    counter = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.number = Model.counter
        Model.counter += 1
```