# How to rapidly check object fields for emptyness

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check for empty values of every field of a distinct object. And I'm tiered of typing it out.

In this case. I have the an object called signal with multiple fields, which should not be empty.

```
if self.is_blank(signal.provider_id):
            error_response = "Signal rejected. No signal provider id given."
        elif self.is_blank(signal.sequence_id):
            error_response = "Signal rejected. No signal sequence id provided."
```

....

```
def is_blank (self, string):
        """Checks for None and empty values"""
        return True if string and string.strip() else False
```

Anyhow, what is the fast way in python to check all fields for "emptiness"? How do we loop them?

Comment: Do you have a list of your fields?

Comment: Beware that `is_blank()` returns `True` if the string is **not** blank! You may either want to rename it, or add a `not` somewhere. I'd recommend rewriting `is_blank()` as `def is_blank(text): return not (text and text.strip())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rostamn mentioned, you can convert your object into a dictionary,
after which you can loop through the (key, values) in a single line with a filter and check the result like so:

```py
any_empty = any([True for x, y in your_obj.__dict__.items() if not y])
```

Change the condition in the loop to the type of empty check you need.

Comment: okay, that is the more amazing shortcut i have ever seen in line of code. thank you

Comment: I'd rather use `any()` and avoid creating the loop. Also `True if condition else False` is typically considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Ternary operators are very useful in many languages any make code **more** readable in my opinion. Python has many common patterns that I consider do consider anti-patterns. There are infinite ways of solving every problem.

Comment: It is not the ternary operator the problem, the problem is that `True if condition else False` is typically better replaced by just `condition` or `bool(condition)` or, in this case, `any(condition)`, i.e. `any(True for x, y in your_obj.__dict__.items() if not y)` which has also the added advantage of not requiring the temporary memory to store the `list`.

Comment: Any is indeed more efficient, casting a non boolean result to bool may work, but seems less readable.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `operator.attrgetter`:

```
def is_blank(self, field_names):
    for name in field_names:
        if getattr(self, name) and getattr(self, name).strip():
            return True, name
    return False, None

...

is_blank, name = self.is_blank(['provider_id', 'sequence_id', ...])
if is_blank:
    print(f'Signal rejected. No signal {name} provided.')
```

You can also implement `is_blank` with `next`:

```
def is_blank(self, field_names):
    return next(
        ((True, name)
         for name in field_names
         if getattr(self, name) and getattr(self, name).strip()),
        (False, None),
    )
```

This is going to print an error message for the first field that is failing the check. All you need to do is to provide a complete list of the attributes to be checked.

Comment: small copy/paste error. `ag = attrgetter(name)`  should be `attrgetter` instead of `operator`

Comment: Why not just `getattr()`? I believe `attrgetter` is mostly useful in its starred form, as it lowers an otherwise explicit looping to a lower level.

Comment: @norok2 You're totally right, I forgot about its existence. Let me fix it

Comment: Also perhaps worth mentioning that `dir(obj)` will provide the full list of `obj` attributes (including the private ones, that one may want to skip), in case one does not want to provide one explicitly.

Comment: this is a better answer than mine

Answer (score 1):

To loop over **all** instance properties you use `my_instance.__dict__`

see this answer for details: [Explain __dict__ attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/explain-dict-attribute)