# Django model relationship infos with on_delete property

Tags: django, django-models

I want to know what models are children of a model to retrieve their `on_delete` property. As I know, like below, if we have `ownerModel` which is parent of `childModel1` and `check1Model`:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class ownerModel(models.Model):
    ownerId = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False, blank=True)

class check1Model(models.Model):
    checkId = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False, blank=True)
    owner=models.ForeignKey(ownerModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class childModel1(models.Model):
    childId = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False, blank=True)
    check2=models.ForeignKey(ownerModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then we can get what models are children of `ownerModel` with a code like this:

```
class myView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields():
            if 'field' in f.__dict__.keys():
                print('***childModels***')
                print(f.__dict__)
                print()
        return Response({'0000'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I mean by checking if the `field` key is in `__dict__.keys()` in items of `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()`.

Of course, here we get extended info about children models:

```
***childModels***
{'field': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: owner>, 'model': <class 'Users.models.ownerModel'>, 'related_name': None, 'related_query_name': None, 'limit_choices_to': {}, 'parent_link': False, 'on_delete': <function 
CASCADE at 0x00000286550848B0>, 'symmetrical': False, 'multiple': True, 'field_name': 'ownerId', 'related_model': <class 'Users.models.check1Model'>, 'hidden': False}

***childModels***
{'field': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: check2>, 'model': <class 'Users.models.ownerModel'>, 'related_name': None, 'related_query_name': None, 'limit_choices_to': {}, 'parent_link': False, 'on_delete': <function CASCADE at 0x00000286550848B0>, 'symmetrical': False, 'multiple': True, 'field_name': 'ownerId', 'related_model': <class 'Users.models.childModel1'>, 'hidden': False}
```

So I find these 2 conditions necessary to get child models info:

1. In child models, making sure child relationship is set up with a line like below:

```
models.ForeignKey(ownerModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

2. As said "if the `field` key is in `__dict__.keys()` in items of `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()`" to get children info.

But the problem is that in some cases I can't get the children info from parent model. So:

1. It makes me wonder if these 2 conditions are enough to find out which models are children of a model?
2. Are there other similar ways to get which models are children of a model?

By the way, I want to have `on_delete` also and having `on_delete` is the only reason I am using `_meta.get_fields()` over `_meta.fields` because `_meta.fields` doesn't provide `on_delete` property.

This is [my code](https://easyupload.io/ou93pt) if you wanna have a look. Note that in full answer I also wanna know what has made problem. So in this case, that `__dict__.keys()` doesn't provide items which don't have `field` in their keys (doesn't provide child model details). Because generally those 2 conditions provide child model details. So later I can get child model details in all codes.

the problem is that even with `for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)` and without any further `if`s doesnt retrieve lines including `on_delete` properties in this project. but in the other projects `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` provides them. and I don't whats the cause that sometimes `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` provides these relationships infos and other times doesnt.

Comment: What do you mean by "with `on_delete` property"? All and only `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField` fields will have an `on_delete` property. Do you want to find all the models that depend on this model? Only foreign keys and one-to-one or also many-to-many?

Comment: yes I want to find the ' find all the models that depend on this model' and their `on_delete` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

After further investigation in the comments, it turned out that the issue was that models were not defined in a `models` submodule. As [stated in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#using-models):

> Once you have defined your models, you need to tell Django you’re going to use those models. Do this by editing your settings file and changing the INSTALLED_APPS setting to add the name of the module that contains your **models.py**.

This requirement can also be confirmed in [Django source code that handles models detection](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9c19aff/django/apps/config.py#L262-L269):

```py
MODELS_MODULE_NAME = "models"


class AppConfig:

    ...

    def import_models(self):
        # Dictionary of models for this app, primarily maintained in the
        # 'all_models' attribute of the Apps this AppConfig is attached to.
        self.models = self.apps.all_models[self.label]

        if module_has_submodule(self.module, MODELS_MODULE_NAME):
            models_module_name = "%s.%s" % (self.name, MODELS_MODULE_NAME)
            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
```

---

**Original answer**

There is no obvious reason why using `__dict__` wouldn't work. However, `__dict__` is not really meant for this kind of usage. This is [not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74463531/1529346) and there is no reason to use it over `hasattr()` for instance.

Here are a few examples of what could go wrong with `__dict__`:

```py
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.foo = 'foobaz'
   ...:         self.bar = 'barbaz'
   ...: 

In [2]: a = A()

In [3]: a.__dict__
Out[3]: {'foo': 'foobaz', 'bar': 'barbaz'}

In [4]: class B(A):
   ...:     @property
   ...:     def bar(self):
   ...:         return 'barfoo'
   ...:     @bar.setter
   ...:     def bar(self, value):
   ...:         pass
   ...: 

In [5]: b = B()

In [6]: b.__dict__
Out[6]: {'foo': 'foobaz'}
# B redefined 'bar' as a property, which removed it from __dict__

In [7]: 'bar' in b.__dict__
Out[7]: False

In [8]: hasattr(b, 'bar')
Out[8]: True

In [9]: class C(A):
   ...:     __slots__ = ('foo', 'bar')
   ...: 

In [10]: c = C()

In [11]: c.foo
Out[11]: 'foobaz'

In [12]: c.bar
Out[12]: 'barbaz'

In [13]: c.__dict__
Out[13]: {}
# C defined 'foo' and 'bar' as slots, which removed them from __dict__

In [14]: hasattr(c, 'foo')
Out[14]: True
```

You could instead use `hasattr()`:

```py
for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields():
    if hasattr(f, 'field'):
        print(f, f.on_delete)
        print()
```

However, checking on the presence of a `field` attribute doesn't seem to be a reliable solution to determine whether the field is a backward relation or not. I would rather recommend to rely on `one_to_one` and `one_to_many` attributes which are `None` for non-relation fields, and `True/False` for relation fields:

```py
for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields():
    if (f.one_to_one or f.one_to_many) and hasattr(f, 'on_delete'):
        print(f, f.on_delete)
        print()
```

I also included `hasattr(f, 'on_delete')` in the condition, to exclude `OneToOneField` relations defined within `ownerModel`. It would probably be cleaner to test `isinstance(f, ForeignObjectRel)` though:

```py
from django.db.models import ForeignObjectRel

for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields():
    if isinstance(f, ForeignObjectRel) and (f.one_to_one or f.one_to_many):
        print(f, f.on_delete)
        print()
```

Comment: hi AntoinePinsard 1st where is ur last answer? 2nd with `if f.one_to_one or f.one_to_many:` there is no `on_delete` info

Comment: I deleted my first answer as I believe it didn't address your issue properly. I can undelete it if you think some information were interesting. As of the issue with `on_delete`, I just noticed that it fails in some specific case. I believe adding the conditon `hasattr(f, 'on_delete')` should be sufficient. Can you confirm?

Comment: the main problem is that `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` doesnt have the lines containing the `{'field': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: owner>, 'model': <class 'Users.models.ownerModel'>, 'related_name': None, 'related_query_name': None, 'limit_choices_to': {}, 'parent_link': False, 'on_delete': <function 
CASCADE at 0x00000286550848B0>, 'symmetrical': False, 'multiple': True, 'field_name': 'ownerId', 'related_model': <class 'Users.models.check1Model'>, 'hidden': False}`

Comment: What do you mean? Why wouldn't it have these lines? What does `f.__dict__` show? I just checked with one of my models: https://bpa.st/RJZA

Comment: let just say that there is an inconsistency in django `._meta.get_fields()`. I know `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` should provide lines that have relationships infos. and in other projects I have used it. but in my new project doesnt work. and I dont know the reason

Comment: I also have provided my codes in highlighted `mycode` link in the question.

Comment: What does `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` return then? We need to figure out what's going wrong, not try to find an alternative way to get what it should return.

Comment: for ie in `PvChatModel._meta.get_fields()` which is supposed to have `PvChatMember` as a child just returns https://onecompiler.com/python/3yp8kbus6 (not its just a text not a code)

Comment: Your models aren't defined in a `models` submodule of your apps. I don't believe Django can detect them properly. See [Using models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#using-models) and [how Django detects models](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9c19aff/django/apps/config.py#L262-L269).

Comment: I think I also had tried to put them back in `models.py` and didnt work. I would check another time.

Comment: thank you AntoinePinsard I tried putting models in `models.py`  it again and solved the problem. so please make the final answer. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

you can find children of a model using `Model._meta.related_objects`

```
# Example Code
from django.utils.functional import classproperty
from django.db import models

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    @classproperty
    def related_objects(cls):
        """
        Return list of related models within the same module
        ManyToManyRel not supported
        """
        related_objects = [
            rel
            for rel in cls._meta.related_objects
            if isinstance(rel, (models.ManyToOneRel, models.OneToOneRel))
        ]
        return [
            (rel.related_model, rel.on_delete)
            for rel in related_objects
            if rel.related_model._meta.app_label == cls._meta.app_label
        ]
```

You can use this class as an `mro` for your models.

Comment: I just added `class Meta` part and the `@classproperty` to one of my existing models and tried to get `model1.related_objects` and it returned `[]` empty list. btw I want to have `on_delete` also and having `on_delete` is the only reason Iam using `_meta.get_fields()` over `_meta.fields` because `_meta.fields` doesnt provide `on_delete` property.

Comment: Please check your code, and i have updated my answer to include `on_delete`.

Comment: @Mike_Jones thanks but I told u that I just added ur code to one of my classes and after that print `model1.related_objects` it returned `[]` (empty list) but supposed to return the children.

Comment: Maybe this doesn't work for the same reason _meta.get_fields() doesn't work

Comment: `Abstract` classes are meant to be inherited `class OwnerModel(SomeModel):`

Comment: even this made no difference

Comment: s24.picofile.com/file/8455316142/ChatTry6.rar.html this my code if u wanna take a look at.

Comment: the problem is I have a code super similar to this code(past versions of this code) and it had no problem with `_meta.get_fields()` regarding showing child models and on_delete

Comment: i don't know what to tell you, i have 30 models relying on this abstract class and they are all returning their children. try remove this condition `if rel.related_model._meta.app_label == cls._meta.app_label` from your code

Comment: it made no difference

Comment: Shoot ! then i really don't what to tell you ...

Comment: thanks mike I also have no clue why these similar codes dont produce the same results

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the backward relationships to this model, you may use `ownerModel._meta.related_objects`. This is however part of Django's private API and isn't officially documented/supported. You can yet find [documentation in the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.3/django/db/models/options.py#L595-L604).

> Return all related objects pointing to the current model. The related objects can come from a one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many field relation type.
>
> Private API intended only to be used by Django itself; `get_fields()` combined with filtering of field properties is the public API for obtaining this field list.

You can also get similar result using [the public API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/meta/#retrieving-all-field-instances-of-a-model) by filtering `get_fields()`:

```py
related_objects = [
    f for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
    if (not f.hidden and (f.one_to_one or f.one_to_many)) or f.many_to_many
]
```

This solution additionally gives you the many-to-many relationships defined within `ownerModel`, which is likely expected if you want many-to-many at all. To exclude all the many-to-many relationships, just remove them from the condition:

```py
related_objects = [
    f for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
    if not f.hidden and (f.one_to_one or f.one_to_many)
]
```

A way to strictly get the backwards relationships only (ie. removing the many-to-many and one-to-one relations defined within the `ownerModel`), could be to test the presence of [`ForeignObjectRel`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.3/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L20-L26) in the field's hierarchy.

```py
from django.db.models import ForeignObjectRel

related_objects = [
    f for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)
    if isinstance(f, ForeignObjectRel) and (not f.hidden or f.many_to_many)
]
```

---

If what you want is to display the value of the `on_delete` property, you can limit the results to one-to-one and one-to-many fields.

```
from django.db.models import ForeignObjectRel

related_objects = [
    f for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields()
    if isinstance(f, ForeignObjectRel)
    and (f.one_to_one or f.one_to_many)
]
for f in related_objects:
    print(f, f.on_delete)
```

Comment: the problem is that even with `for f in ownerModel._meta.get_fields(include_hidden=True)` and without any further `if`s there are no lines including `on_delete` properties in this project. but in the other projects `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` provides them. and I don't whats the cause that sometimes `ownerModel._meta.get_fields()` provides these relationships infos and other times doesnt.

Comment: and the problem is not related to ability take some key from the `__dict__` or `hasattr()`