# Loading YOLO8 in pytorch nn.module

Tags: python, pytorch, load, yolov8

I have trained a yolov8n and now need to do inferences using pytorch, but I don't know how to properly import/convert the layers to load.

I can make predictions in YOLO using model.predict(), but I need to load this like in pytorch format.

If I understand correctly, to load a pytorch model, I need to create an architecture instance from nn.module and then load it this way:

```
# Define model
class TheModelClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TheModelClass, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
```

But in YOLO8 I only have the weights ('best.pt') and I don't know how to load them using pytorch.

I checked that when I load the ".yaml" file from ultralytics, I get the model summary:

```
Running this:
model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch

Returns this:
                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    897664  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [80, [64, 128, 256]]          
YOLOv8n summary: 225 layers, 3157200 parameters, 3157184 gradients, 8.9 GFLOPs

<class 'ultralytics.yolo.engine.model.YOLO'>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you manage to recreate it?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can load the pretrained model as you did and then, to retrieve the underlying torch model, you can do something like:

```py
import torch

torch_model: torch.nn.modules.container.Sequential = model.model.__dict__["_modules"]["model"]
```

and wrap it into your own class.

> Note: I do not guarantee you this is the best method, but it works as
> of today. If internals change, this breaks :)

How did I find it? You might ask. Generally when I am exploring library internals I start to inspect the ***dict*** dundler method, that lets you quickly understand the attributes of a given class. (well it's more subtle than that, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907442/explain-dict-attribute) you can find more info about it).